# Sync code across computers

Tags: synchronization

Right now I manage a small team of developers.  We use subversion for all of our code.  Interested to know if there is a tool that enables developers to all work from the same code base versus each having their own local code?

Comment: You need to post why you want to do that.

Answer (score 12):

There are many ways to do this but I don't think you should try.  Private working copies of source code is a proven method that was created specifically to prevent developers from having to work on a single copy of the code base.

Source control is a *good thing* and I wouldn't recommend moving away from it.

Answer (score 4):

I dont quite understand your question. Maybe you need source control system like **git** or **bazaar** - they have local branches (each dev may have his own) and allow *sync'ing* code with centralized repositories.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* put the code on a network share, but I highly agree with Andrew Hare's view that you should stick with private working copies (+1 to his answer from me).

If you could post your reason behind this question, perhaps the community can help you find a good solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot possibly be what you want. The whole point of using source code control is so that you **don't** work on the same physical copy of your source tree.

Please elaborate on what problem you **really** want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it seems like you aren't using SVN correctly.  SVN enable you to all use the same code base.  The code base is stored in the svn repository.  You edit your local copy, and then when you are satisfied with those changes, you commit them to SVN.  If you want a copy of the current code base, you can export it from SVN.  Editing your own local copy and then committing to the repository ensures that you aren't overwriting anybody else's changes.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Andrew Hare, source control is a good thing and should be used. It enables you to roll back one developers changes in a very controlled way